# Using strftime as . File Name

Tags: python, csv, pandas, export-to-csv

Trying to write `to_csv` with the following code:

```
file_name = time.strftime("Box_Office_Data_%Y/%m/%d_%H:%M.csv")
allFilms.to_csv(file_name)
```

But am getting the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-aa2d6e13e9af> in <module>()
      9 
     10 file_name = time.strftime("Box_Office_Data_%Y/%m/%d_%H:%M.csv")
---> 11 allFilms.to_csv(file_name)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, tupleize_cols, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal, **kwds)
   1187                                      escapechar=escapechar,
   1188                                      decimal=decimal)
-> 1189         formatter.save()
   1190 
   1191         if path_or_buf is None:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/format.py in save(self)
   1440         else:
   1441             f = com._get_handle(self.path_or_buf, self.mode,
-> 1442                                 encoding=self.encoding)
   1443             close = True
   1444 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/common.py in _get_handle(path, mode, encoding, compression)
   2827                 f = open(path, mode, encoding=encoding)
   2828             else:
-> 2829                 f = open(path, mode, errors='replace')
   2830         else:
   2831             f = open(path, mode)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Box_Office_Data_2015/09/24_22:11.csv'
```

Since I'm writing to a csv, why would it be searching for a file/directory that is not yet created?

Anyone's help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: The filename is illegal.  / indicates a directory, not sure about :.  Replace all the / and : with either - or _.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear -

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Box_Office_Data_2015/09/24_22:11.csv'
```

If you get this error when trying to do `.to_csv()` , it means that the directory in which you are trying to save the file does not exist. So in your case, the directory - `Box_Office_Data_2015/09/` does not exist. It seems like you actually meant `Box_Office_Data_2015/09/24_22:11.csv` to be a filename (with no directory) , I am not sure if that would be possible `09/` would be considered as a directory.

A simple solution would be to use something other than `/` in between the year/month/day . Example -

```
file_name = time.strftime("Box_Office_Data_%Y_%m_%d_%H:%M.csv")
allFilms.to_csv(file_name)
```

Comment: Sorry, this is clear enough - just  been a long day :( appreciate the support

Answer (score 0):

In your code `file_name = time.strftime("Box_Office_Data_%Y/%m/%d_%H:%M.csv")`.

File name was like this `Box_Office_Data_2015/09/24_22:11.csv`, which means a path to a file.

Try to replace the `/` with something like `_`.

Try this:

`file_name = time.strftime("Box_Office_Data_%Y_%m_%d_%H:%M.csv")`